# latexmkrc and subfiles

Tags: latexmk, subfiles

I have a LaTeX-Project that is split into multiple files using the package `subfiles`. The project has the following structure:

```
main.tex
.latexmkrc
lib/custom-class.cls
lib/custom-package.sty
foo/bar.tex
foo/image.png
baz/...
```

I use `latexmkrc` to include the class- and package-files in `lib` in `TEXINPUTS`:

```
ensure_path( 'TEXINPUTS', 'lib//' )
```

The project builds correctly when I build `main.tex`, but when I build one of the subfiles (e.g. `for/bar.tex`) I get the error

```
File `custom-class.cls` not found.
```

I realise this is because `.latexmkrc` is not used when building in a subdirectory. I found a [discussion](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/1895) on the GitHub-Page of the VSCode-extension LaTeX-Workshop (which I am using) and the best solution there seems to be to just copy and paste `.latexmkrc` into the subdirectories – the issue is that I have many (20 or so) subdirectories and I want to avoid having to change all these files whenever I change the main `.latexmkrc`, especially since I am not the only one working on this project. Is there any other way, or can I, perhaps, create a `.latexmkrc` in each of the subdirectories that just imports the main `.latexmkrc`?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: (a) I don't think copying and pasting would work, since the relative path is wrong (from the base directory it is `lib/` but from `foo/` it should be `../lib/`). This can be solved if you use absolute paths instead. (b) To have the same file show up in multiple folders is a textbook case of what [symbolic links](https://www.howtogeek.com/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) are good for.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't think about the problem with the path being relative... using absolute paths would break when building on a different system – and would symbolic links work with git? As in, does git recognise that they are symbolic, or would git recognise 20 different files in the different subdirectories?

Comment: For the path problem, if you don't worry about possible injection issues, you can add both `./lib/` and `../lib/` to the search path. The question about [git and symlink is more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links), but it should work if you configure things right (and create the symlinks using relative paths and not absolute paths).

Comment: Another option, since you are working with `git`, is that you can implement a post-commit hook that copies (perhaps even with appropriate `sed`ing to replace the paths) the `.latexmkrc` to the appropriate directories. You just need to make sure that all edits are made to the main `.latexmkrc` and the generated ones are not tracked by `git` (which you can help by putting them all in `.gitignore`.)

Comment: That is some git magic I did not know about. I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: If you use hooks though: you will want it both post-commit (so that changes to `.latexmkrc` are propagated on commit) and post-checkout (so that changes made by others are propagated). Also note that hooks are by default local, so you have to coordinate with your collaborators to install their own local hooks. In either case you will need your collaborators to check on some configs.

Comment: Actually: one final non-git related solution. IIRC latexmkrc can contain perl system calls. So you could craft a solution using a base directory `latexmkrc` whereby running `latexmk` in the base directory creates the appropriate `latexmkrc` files for all the subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your last comment got me thinking and I just added .latexmkrc files to all subdirectories containing only the line ```do '../.latexmkrc';``` This works perfectly since I do not worry about injection issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following lines at the very beginning of the main file:

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{lib/}{../lib/}}
\makeatother
```

This sets the input path to the directories where to search for additional files, from both perspectives (main directory and subfolder `foo`).

I tested this approach with the following sample project:

```
% main.tex
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{lib/}{../lib/}}
\makeatother
\documentclass{custom-class}
\usepackage{custom-package}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\subfile{foo/bar.tex}
\end{document}

% foo/bar.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image.png}
\end{document}

% cp `kpsewhich example-image.png foo/image.png`

% lib/custom-class.cls
\LoadClass{article}

% lib/custom-package.sty
\endinput
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a great solution since I only use latexmk to set ```TEXINPUTS``` and quick preliminary testing suggests it works well. I found another solution more akin to what Willie Wong suggested (see comments on the question), but I will accept your answer. If someone needs this with more functionality of ```latexmk``` the solution in the comments should work.